# how to append a dispatchEvent containing data to a class with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having problems with my script and i can't see the problem with it myself:

```
    $("#mainsub").append(newRow + "<div class='showMore' onclick='document.dispatchEvent(expand, { 'postId': " + pf.id + " })'>Show More</div></div>");
```

My webkit debugger is saying: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;" when i click on the element.

has anyone run into this before? is there a problem with the line of code?

EDIT:** newRow looks like this:

```
    var newRow = "<div id=" + pf.id + ">"+rowContents;
```

rowContents is:

```
    rowContents += "<div class='"+tagName+"'>"+tag.text()+"</div>";
```

tag name is just from some xml i am parsing.

Another edit: I'm just going to put the whole function in just in case this is helpful

```
pf.parseResults = function(){
    $("#mainsub").empty();
    var $xml = $(pf.xml);
    var $query = $xml.find('query_result').children().each(function() {
        var row = $(this);
        var rowContents = "";
        row.children().each(function() {
            var tag = $(this);
            var tagName = tag[0].tagName;
            if(tagName != "ID"){
                rowContents += "<div class='"+tagName+"'>"+tag.text()+"</div>";
            }
            if(tagName === "ID"){
                pf.id = tag.text();
            }
        });
        var newRow = "<div id=" + pf.id + ">" + rowContents;
        $("#mainsub").append(newRow + "<div class='showMore' onclick='document.dispatchEvent(expand, { \'postId\': " + pf.id + " })'>Show More</div></div>");// this fires an event with data attached listing the id of the element the user tapped/**/
    });
    $("#mainsub").append("<div onclick='document.dispatchEvent(nextPage)'><p>Next</p></div>");// figure out how to not show next when there will not be another page
    if(pf.getPage > 0){
        $("#mainsub").append("<div onclick='document.dispatchEvent(previousPage)'><p>Previous</p></div>");// show go to previous as long at it will exist
    }
};
```

Comment: This will be an issue with what the variable `newRow` contains. Please post what `newRow` is.

Comment: after a bit going a bit deeper at my code i found through looking in the elements tab of developer tool that (though ElmoVanKielmo had provided the correct answer to the question) the javascript interpreter was replacing \' with " instead of ' when rendering to html. not sure if it was a bug with the webkit version i am using (Intel XDK). hope this helps anyone else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you nest quotes of the same type (single quotes in your case) you have to escape them like this:

```
    $("#mainsub").append(newRow + "<div class='showMore' onclick='document.dispatchEvent(expand, { \'postId\': " + pf.id + " })'>Show More</div></div>");
```

*As this line of code is quite long and I didn't wand to change too much, I'll point out that escaped quotes are in this `expand, { \'postId\': " + pf.id + " }` fragment.*

Comment: I am still getting the error after this.. Is there anything else wrong you can see? Anything else you need to look at?

Comment: There are no more syntax errors in the posted code.